# Picking $k$ people from a group of $n$ people where each person is identical

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I am going through "How to Count" by Beeler and I saw this exercise:

Each club in the college must select two senators to represent them
at council. How many possible council meetings are possible if there are five clubs,
the $i$th club has $n_i$ members, and no one is in two clubs.

This is my interpretation of the problem.

I will assume that each club member is indistinguishable from each other. Then we will just choose 2 members from each group of $n_i$ from $1 \leq i \leq 5$, giving us,

$$\binom{n_1}{2}\cdot\binom{n_2}{2}\cdot\binom{n_3}{2}\cdot\binom{n_4}{2}\cdot\binom{n_5}{2}$$

The reason why we can do this is because each group member is indistinguishable-- we do not care about order. We are finding out every possible combination of a 2-set from each group of $n_i$.

We CANNOT do this:

$$n_1(n_1-1)\cdot n_2(n_2-1)\cdot n_3(n_3-1)\cdot n_4(n_4-1)\cdot n_5(n_5-1)$$

This is explained by the fact that we have $n_i$ ways to choose our first member, then $n_i-1$ ways to choose our second member. HOWEVER this takes into account order, which we don't want. Once we choose two members, they are senators-- the order in which they were picked is irrelevant.

Are these interpretations correct?

Comment: Yes, the choose notation takes into account the dividing by 2! on each term to cancel out the ordering

Comment: The only problem with your posted analysis is your statement that "each group member is indistinguishable".  Under that scenario, the correct enumeration would be $1^5 = 1$, since each group would have only 1 *distinguishable* pair.  The idea of indistinguishable people would be consistent with each group having $n_i$ people each of whom was a genetic clone of all of the other $(n_i - 1)$ people.

Comment: And yet there is a "conspiracy" of sorts to somehow convert indistinguishable objects into distinguishable ones. Consider, e.g. $5$ red balls and $3$ red balls. How many ways can we *select* $3$ balls ? One answer is $\binom83 = 56$ ways, which somehow imparts distinguishability to indistinguishable balls of a color, and ties in the answer with probability. I haven't seen any answer of the form $3+0, 2+1, 1+2, \;and\; 0+3 = 4$ ways

Comment: @trueblueanil Agreed, assuming that you intended "...$3$ *blue* balls" (for example).  However, while the *conspiracy* is focused among mathSE reviewers, and while the notion  of $5$ red, $3$ blue only has meaning if red balls are indistinguishable, I (subjectively) feel that the situation is not so clear cut.  mathSE is inundated with (very ?) poorly composed problems, some caused by OP *filtration*, and some caused by the original problem composer.  So, the mathSE reviewer is often (almost) compelled to trot out his telepathic skills.